# Surjective morphism to structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a non-singular algebraic variety, $\mathcal{O}_X$ the structure sheaf. We know that an inclusion of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules

> $0\rightarrow \mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$

implies that $\mathcal{F}$ is an ideal sheaf. I want to know if we have a surjective morphism

> $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow 0$

then what information of $\mathcal{F}$ can we get?

Comment: It follows that $\mathcal{F}$ is an extension of $\mathcal{O}_X$ by another sheaf.

Comment: @Sasha Thank you very much. Do we have a sufficient condition of the existence of surjective morphisms $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$?

Comment: Sure, if $\mathcal{F}^\vee$ has a nowhere vanishing section, then a surjection exists.